# Node не видит Express

Tags: node-modules

[image: Код и ошибка]

Подскажите в чём проблема, Node не видит модуль express, пробовал разные версии нода, переустанавливал express и глобально и локально, толку 0

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello, World'))
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Listening on port 4000!'))


PS C:\Projects\notedly\api> node src index
```

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:

- C:\Projects\notedly\api\src\index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
  at Object. (C:\Projects\notedly\api\src\index.js:3:17)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\Projects\notedly\api\src\index.js' ]
  }

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте ошибки и код в виде картинок.

Comment: const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello, World'))
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Listening on port 4000!'))

Comment: Добавьте это в текст вопроса нажав "Править"

Comment: А зачем rsc и index разделять пробелом?

Comment: А как вы express устанавливали?

Comment: Вообще это готовый код для обучения, всё необходимое там подтягивается через npm install, но так же через инстал экспресс устанавливал